# Can records (such as accounts, contacts, and opportunities) be shared with Partner Community users?

Tags: community, permissions, sharing, partner-communities, sharing-rule

A client wants to explicitly share private data with Partner Community users. For example, their Salesforce administrator needs to share `Account A` with `Partner User A`, but `Partner User B` should not have access.

According to [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/212100/12290), a Customer Community Plus license gains access to data just like a regular Salesforce user license. So, does a Partner Community license have the same access?

If so, the administrator should be able share (using the "Sharing" button) a specific record with specific groups, roles, or a specific Partner Community user, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, once you [enable External Sharing](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_owd_external.htm&type=5), you can share records with the following types of users:

- Authenticated website users
- Chatter external users
- Community users
- Customer Portal users
- Guest users
- High-volume portal users
- Partner Portal users
- Service Cloud Portal users

Comment: A custom component (Apex) running is system mode can do anything you want

Comment: @avjit Are you sure that a custom component (Apex) - whatever that is - will work? For example, customer community licenses can never see Opportunities. How would you expose those?